# CakePHP not inserting into model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My Model:

```
class BuyItPackage extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'BuyItPackage';

    var $belongsTo = array('User', 'Auction');

    function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null){
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }

}
```

My save action:

```
function add($user_id = null, $auction_id = null)
{
    $this->BuyItPackage->create(); // this is line 23

    $data = array (
            'BuyItPackage' => array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'auction_id' => $auction_id,
                'name' => '',
                'price' => 0.00,
                'contract' => '',
                'points' => 0
            )
        );
    $this->BuyItPackage->save($data);
}
```

When I navigate to the add() action this error is generated

```
Undefined property: BuyItPackagesController::$BuyItPackage [APP/controllers/buy_it_packages_controller.php, line 23]
```

No data is inserted, it looks like it cannot find my model, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your data in an array and save it by save Method.

```
$this->data["BuyItPackage"]['user_id'] = $user_id;
$this->data["BuyItPackage"]['auction_id'] = $auction_id;
$this->data["BuyItPackage"]['name'] = 'dummyvalue1';
$this->data["BuyItPackage"]['price'] = '0.00';
$this->data["BuyItPackage"]['contract'] = 'dummyvalue2';
$this->data["BuyItPackage"]['points'] = '0';

$this->BuyItPackage->save($this->data["BuyItPackage"], false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason you need the `->create();` line at all in this case.

I would guess there's also something wrong w/ how your controller is started, but we can't see that, so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model is not attached to your controller. Maybe you redefined the `$uses` variable of your controller. If so, you need to make sure to add  'BuyItPackage' to this variable, otherwise it's no longer loaded by default.

```
class BuyItPackagesController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array ('BuyItPackage', 'OtherModel');

    function add($user_id = null, $auction_id = null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```